# There are 20 red marbles, 10 blue marbles, and 5 white marbles in a jar.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There are 20 red marbles, 10 blue marbles, and 5 white marbles in a jar.  Select a marble without looking, note the color, and then replace the marble in the jar.  We’re interested in the number of marbles you would have to draw in order to be sure you have a red marble.

I am pretty sure that this experiment can be modelled by a geometric distribution where my probability of success is $p=  {20 \over35}$ and $X$=Number of drawn marbles until I draw the first red.

I would then have used the pmf of the geometric distribution $P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$, where $P(X=k)=1$ since I want to be sure to have one red marble and  $p=  {20 \over35}$. Apprently that yields a wrong result. I would appreciate any help or hint!

Comment: You can never be certain you will draw a red, as you could in principle keep drawing whites or blues, so P will never be 1

Comment: Ahh yeah well i overread the line with replacement. Now I solved it for no replacement, where the answer would be 16 of course, but I am still stuck with replacement.

Comment: You could ask the question what is the *expected* number of marbles you would have to draw to get a red...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The probability of not drawing a red ball after $k$ turns is given by $(1-p)^k$.

Thus if we want to ensure that a red ball is chosen before $k$ turns, then the probability of not drawing a red ball after $k$ turns must be $0$.  That is,

$(1-p)^k = 0$

Therefore,

$(1-p) = 0$

Thus,

$p = 1$

Therefore in order to be sure a red ball is chosen after $k$ turns, the probability of choosing a red ball at any turn must be 1.  But since $p = \frac{25}{30}$, it is not possible to find a $k$ such that you can be sure of drawing a red ball before $k$ turns.